# How to create database table in Google App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine

How to create database table in Google App Engine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. You create [Entities](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html) of different kinds. Datastore is not a relational database[*].

If you want to imagine that GAE creates one "table" for each kind, the "columns" of that "table" being the properties of the entities, then you're welcome to do so. But I don't think it helps.

[*] I don't know whether it meets some technical definition, but it certainly doesn't drive like SQL-based databases.

Comment: Are you sure, I am learning development on Google App engine and its says somewhere it has support for SQL like thing.

Comment: @sushilbharwani: GAE has changed since I wrote this answer. At the time it was just datastore, now there's Google Cloud SQL too.

Comment: thanks Steve, I have a question related to GAE which i am asking from so long nobody answered Can i use create a Web Application on Google Apple Engine which is independent of Google database or API's and can be ran any server like tomcat jboss etc

Comment: I've never used Java on GAE, only Python. I would expect there to be some differences between the "Tomcat" and "GAE" versions of your application. With care you could arrange things so that most of the code is the same, and the code that's different is collected into specific classes where you have a different class for each environment, implementing a common interface.

Comment: thanks Steve actually i also started with GAE and was unaware of both python and java. But since i learned java in college i preferred it over python.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

> App Engine Datastore is a schemaless object datastore providing
>   robust, scalable storage for your web application, with the following
>   features:
>
> - No planned downtime
> - Atomic transactions
> - High availability of reads and writes
> - Strong consistency for reads and ancestor queries
> - Eventual consistency for all other queries 
>      The Python Datastore interface includes a rich data modeling API and a SQL-like query language called GQL.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words just create you model class, create an object of this class and after first call of put() method for this object the "table"(I think the term here is kind) will be created on the fly. But you definitely have to read the documentation and check some examples. The will help you to understand the specifics of Google Datastore and how it differs from the common RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, i would say that with [Google BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) you don't need to create your tables because there are already [six Big Tables](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown.html#anc-tables) ready to store [whatever you want](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html).